# Differentiating $f(x)=\frac{3(1-\sin x)}{2\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I'm having trouble to solve the following derivative. I tried to apply the quotient rule, but I cannot get the same result as my textbook.

The function:

$$f(x)=\frac{3(1-\sin x)}{2\cos x}$$

The result I supposed to get:

$$f'(x)=\frac{3}{2}\sec x(\tan x-\sec x)$$

I have tried this by applying the quotient rule:

$$f(x) =\frac{3(1-\sin x)}{2\cos x}=\frac{3-3\sin x}{2\cos x}$$
\begin{align*}
f'(x) & =\frac{-3\cos x \cdot 2\cos x - (3- \sin x) \cdot -2\sin x}{2\cos^2x}\\
      & =\frac{-6\cos^2x-(-6\sin x+6\sin^2x)}{2\cos^2x}\\
      & =\frac{-6\cos^2x+6\sin x+6\sin^2x}{2\cos^2x}
\end{align*}

Is someone able to show me step by step how to get the above result?

Thank you in advance for all of your help!

Comment: And, what's your solution? Maybe, they are the same.

Comment: Hint: You can write $\dfrac{3 \left( 1 - \sin x \right)}{2 \cos x} = \dfrac{3}{2} \left[ \sec x - \tan x \right]$. Then, you can use the fact that derivative operator is linear to get to your answer in just one step.

Comment: So far, my solution is: $\frac{-6cos^2x+6sinx+6sin^2x}{2cos^2x}$

Comment: Please edit your post showing [what you have tried](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). We have no way of knowing if that step is correct, or which step you might have gone wrong based on your comment alone.

Comment: @TobyMak I added what I have tried.

Comment: It is really hard to correct your work. Taking out a factor of $\frac{3}{2}$ will make your calculations so much easier. In general when solving these kinds of questions, you should aim to simplify as much as possible before taking the derivative.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac{3(1-\sin x)}{2\cos x} =\frac {3}{2} (\frac {1-\sin x}{\cos x})$$

Apply the quotient rule $$ f'(x) =\frac {3}{2}( \frac {-\cos x (\cos x)+\sin x (1-\sin x)}{\cos ^2 x})=$$

$$\frac {3}{2}( \frac {\sin x -1}{\cos ^2 x})=$$

$$\frac {3}{2}( \frac {1}{\cos x} \frac {\sin x -1}{\cos x})=$$

$$\frac {3}{2} \sec x(\tan x - sec x)$$